# Connect Gitlab vscode extension to own Gitlab instance

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, vscode-extensions

When I give the instance URL and my access token to connect the extension to instance. I am getting this error
`http://Gitlab-instanceURL/api/v4/user failed, reason: certificate signature failure`.
In git config I have set **sslVerify to false**.
In vs code i don't see any settings to do that.
I tried `gitlab.ignoreCertificationErrors: true` in settings.json

Can anyone guide me how to fix this and connect the extension to the instance.